# iPad mini apps not fitting screen

Tags: ios, ipad, applications

Sometimes, I install apps for iPhone on my iPad and they are too small and doesn't fit the screen. Is there any option to resize them so they have either no black space around or just on one side?

Answer (score 1):

This a the behaviour defined by Apple for iPhone apps on iPad. There is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not seeing the 2x button in the lower right-hand corner which will scale iPhone apps up to fill the iPad screen? I’ve never seen an iOS app that doesn’t fill the screen on an iPad.